# Arduino Multiplex RFID

Tags: arduino, rfid

I want to build an Arduino based  chessboard using Multiplex RFID to identify pieces.
I have already build a version using reed switches see chess.fortherapy.co.uk .

Having 64 readers would be too expensive.I am assuming that by using multiplexed antenna I can keep the cost of readers down for my 8x8 matrix.

A previous post talked about using relays, but with no further detail can someone help by explaining the basic component layout I would use.

Comment: Can you explain the idea behind "multiplexed antenna". It seems that an explanation of this is needed first.

Comment: PIN diodes can be used to switch RF instead of mechanical relays.

Answer (score 2):

There are silicon RF multiplexers available. It will be a much simpler prospect if you are using a lower frequency RFID, as it will be more tolerant to layout and mux-type components.

Here is an example of a DC-2.5GHz RF switch: (only an example, I know little of your application!)
http://www.analog.com/en/rfif-components/rf-switches/adg904/products/product.html

However it is likely, that the previous post you mentioned offers a simpler solution; using relays. RF relays are not too difficult to come by, but can be fairly expensive. (ie. perhaps more than a bunch of RFID readers...)